# Send iMessage to group chat

Tags: applescript, imessage, osascript

How can you send a iMessage to a group chat? I have searched everywhere and I can't find anything. I want to send it to a group chat named something, possibly If I get a list of buddies in the chat I can send it to everyone at once? A problem may be that I'm also in the chat, so that might be a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To send to an existing group chat, you will need to obtain the chat's internal guid. There are 2 methods of doing this.

1. Extract it from the messages.app internal database, located on disk at `~/Library/Messages/chat.db`. It is the guid column under the chat table. If you have the group chat named it will be easy to find by display_name.
2. You can use an AppleScript handler for Messages with the `on chat room message received` handler to capture the ID when someone posts in that chat.

Once you have the guid (should in a format similar to `iMessage;+;chat831551415676550949`), you can use AppleScript to send the message.

```
tell application "Messages"
  set myid to "iMessage;+;chat831551415676550949"
  set mymessage to "Hello World"
  set theBuddy to a reference to text chat id myid
  send mymessage to theBuddy
end tell
```

To send an image, replace the mymessage text with:

```
set ImageAttachment to POSIX file "File path here" as alias
```

Comment: Do note that Apple will now prevent you from accessing chat.db with a Permission Denied error. The only way to bypass it (based on my past trial and error) is to copy the file elsewhere and access that instead. E.g. `cp ~/Library/Messages/chat.db /tmp/chat.db` then use `/tmp/chat.db`

Comment: @py660 You can bypass the protection on chat.db by enabling Full Disk Access for your application in settings under Privacy & Security

Answer (score 0):

This works for sending to existing iMessage group chats:

```
tell application "Messages"
    set _account to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
    set _chat to 1st chat whose name = "<GROUP CHAT NAME>"
    send "hello world" to _chat
end tell
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35698025)